# Расширение стандартной панели с табами

Tags: gwt, javascript, java, css

У меня имеется стандартная панель с табами (DecoratedTabPanel). Задача сводится к тому, чтобы добавить несколько кнопок в панель, а именно в ее верхнюю часть, там где находятся заголовки табов. Посмотрел все методы, стандартного способа не нашел.

Если посмотреть код страницы, кнопки должны находиться в диве с классом "gwt-TabBarRest".

Возможно ли так разместить кнопки или надо делать свою панель табов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю, что это самое лучшее решение, но оно работать будет

Нам необходимо найти элемент с классом "gwt-TabBarRest"

```
private Element getRestBar(Element current){
    if (current == null)
        return null;

    if (current.getClassName().equals("gwt-TabBarRest"))
        return current;

    Element child = current.getFirstChildElement();
    while(child != null){
        Element tmp = getRestBar(child);
        if(tmp != null)
            return tmp;

        child = child.getNextSiblingElement();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Для добавления панельки с кнопками делаем так:

```
Element element = getRestBar(getTabBar().getElement());
if (element != null)
    element .appendChild(addPanel.getElement());
```

Сначала идея с поиском по классу показалось слишком большим хаком, потом подумав, что стандартные элементы мы стилизируем по классам, вроде кажется и ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите свой класс! В нем будет ваш таб и верхняя панель. Придумайте методы добавления кнопок на панель и т.д.